# Package Makefile error in OpenWRT Attitude adjustment

Tags: openwrt, buildroot

I am changing the question as I could get over the initial issue.

I am having the following define in my package//Makefile

```
PKG_BUILD_DIR:=$(KERNEL_BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_NAME)-$(PKG_VERSION)
define Build/Compile
    $(MAKE) -s -C $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
endef
$(eval $(call BuildPackage,<Module-name>))
```

I am trying to get a custom kernel module to compile with OpenWRT.

I am building using the command make package/"Module_name"/compile ;

Make never succeeds and it comes out saying :

```
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `compile'.
```

Why is make coming out doing nothing eventhough rule exists ? Any suggestion to get over this error would be helpful.

Comment: Also let me know whether I have to use KernelPackage or BuildPackage ?

Answer (score 1):

Please first run

```
make menuconfig
```

and check if the module your are trying to compile is selected in the OpenWRT configuration.
If the module is selected then it will be built as you are trying to do.